# pam_mount + sshfs + port != 22

Tags: mount, pam, cifs, sshfs

How can i configure my volume in ~/.pam_mount.conf.xml so set a different port for ssh?

Currently, default (using port 22) this works:

```
<volume options="nosuid,nodev" 
    user="yourUsername" 
    mountpoint="~/mountpoint" 
    path="sshfs#%(USER)@server:" fstype="fuse" />
```

Thanks for hints. 
G. does help and manpage shows not the right way for me to find out.

Kind regards 
flobee

Answer (score 0):

I got it.
A working local ssh config must exists. Than it works :-)

Comment: The file ~/.ssh/config incl. the settings to the correct host, port, ssh key... to connect to. man 5 ssh_config